# Correct way to auto load nested directory. Why the trailing forward slash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This works (with the trailing forward slash):

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join("lib", "**/")]
```

This doesn't work (without the slash):

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join("lib", "**")]
```

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trailing slash indicates to `Dir[]` that it should list directories recursively.

Let's have a deeper look.

```
Rails.root.join("lib", "**")
```

Returns a path to `#{Rails.root}/lib/**`, while

```
Rails.root.join("lib", "**/")
```

returns a path to `#{Rails.root}/lib/**/`.

This is then passed on to `Dir[]`. `**`, in the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob), says that it matches directories recursively. But without the trailing slash, it seems to have the same behaviour as with `*`. If you do something like `**/*.rb`, it lists, *recursively*, all the files ending in `.rb`. So what you're really specifying with the trailing slash, is that you want to search for directories, as they always end in `/`.

Comment: what's the difference between `Rails.root.join("lib", "**/")` and `Rails.root.join("lib", "**"/ "*")`?

Comment: The latter one matches files.